# How bad does a broken heart hurt me?

Tags: mystic-messenger

I am on Yoosung's route, and I got a broken heart during one of the chat conversations. How much does that hurt me? Can I still recover and get the good ending?

Answer (score -1):

It mostly counts as taking one heart away, so it doesn't hurt too much. 
though it does make you feel bad.